# Chrome Won't Load HTML5 Videos

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a training website full of videos with a jquery navigation bar.

All videos with text descriptions are loaded within there own div tags.

All div tags are made hidden through `display: none;` and when a user clicks on a section of the jquery navigation the cosponsoring div tag is displayed through  `display: block;`

My whole system works great In FireFox, Safari and Internet Explorer.

However chrome just keeps processing the page and doesn't stop. As well as this the second half of videos in my HTML are just not being playable at all.

Every other browser loads the page immediately and the navigation works perfectly to see all the videos available.

HTML5 videos are being displayed with code like below:

```
            <video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" controls>

                <source src="6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer/_/video/mp4/part-4-2-effgijfrcx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer/_/video/ogv/part-4-2-effgijfrcx.ogv" type="video/ogg">

                Oppps! Your browser appears to not be able to play this video. Please update it!

            </video>
```

Comment: I don't know what jQuery has to do with anything but your exact markup works in my Chrome using mp4 so not enough information.

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the fact I have 15 or so videos in my HTML that are hidden through CSS. Chrome seems to try to load them all, it only loads around 8 before no more of the videos become playable when they are made visible through CSS by my jquery navigation. The chrome page is forever processing.. Every other browser doesn't seem to have a problem loading immediately and all videos load flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is pretty typical of Chrome. Chrome is trying to load all 15 videos at the same time, but it only allows itself so many simultaneous open connections to the server. It has no way of knowing which videos to prioritize.

I suggest adding `preload="metadata"` to all of your video tags. When a given video becomes visible, you can call `.load()` on it to start buffering. Or just begin playing it.

I have a more detailed explanation in a case study that faced the same problem:
http://www.pbs.org/pov/blog/povdocs/2014/09/empire-case-study-part-1/

You *may* still run into problems if the user starts revealing many videos in rapid succession. In that case, you may want to force hidden videos to stop buffering by setting `src` to empty string and then calling `.load()`. You'll have to set the `src` again when that video is revealed again.